# Заполнить lookup в таблице React material ui table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, datatable, material-ui

Что-то не получается заполнить lookup в таблице. у меня есть объект с массивом, и я хочу им заполнить данный выпадающий список, пытаюсь сделать так: `{ title: "Album", field: "albumName", lookup:{...songs.albums }}];` Массив приходит всё ок, но как это дело корректно заполнить..

Comment: Что лежит в `songs.albums`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
const oList = []
items.map( (item,index) =>
      oList.push(
<option value="grapefruit">item</option>
      )
)

return 
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
{oList}
</select>
```